# Submit to Eloqua Form Without Eloqua Processing Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, eloqua

When a form is submitted from our web pages, which are tied to Eloqua, the user is sent to a processing page, and then based on processing rules for the form is redirected to a set URL.

I'd simply like to asynchronously do the form submission, and then keep the user on the current page without taking them to a processing page. I can use jquery to hide the form after submission and show my own thank you message, but it seems Eloqua is set in its ways.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit the eloqua payload using ajax to their REST API in a custom js function.  In the success callback, perform any functionality you desire on the page.

Comment: The function is not working for me. Can you explain ?? with URL ??